# Error with List<T>.Contains(T) in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Wondering why this doesn't work.  Insight appreciated.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> foo = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        var myResult = MyTest<int>(foo);
    }

    private static List<int> MyTest<T>(List<T> input)
    {
        List<int> bar = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };
        return bar.Where(b => input.Contains(b)).ToList();
    }
```

Expected output from MyTest() is a List { 2, 3 }.  However, the compiler reports two errors on `input.Contains(b)`, as follows:

1. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'T'
2. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(T)' has some invalid arguments

This Where() clause works fine if I don't use generic lists.

This is a simplification of my real-world problem, so please don't get stuck on "why are you writing this?"  The problem is the error and why it's occurring.

**Revised for (hopefully) clarity:**

```
namespace SandBox
{

class Foo
{
    public int FooInt { get; set; }
    public string FooString { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private static List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo> {
            new Foo() {FooInt = 1, FooString = "A"},
            new Foo() {FooInt = 2, FooString = "B"},
            new Foo() {FooInt = 3, FooString = "C"}
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> myIntList = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
        var myFirstResult = GetFoos<int>(myIntList);

        List<string> myStringList = new List<string> { "A", "B" };
        var mySecondResult = GetFoos<string>(myStringList);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a list of Foo objects that match the input parameter list
    /// </summary>
    private static List<Foo> GetFoos<T>(List<T> input)
    {
        //***
        // Imagine lots of code here that I don't want to duplicate in 
        // an overload of GetFoos()
        //***

        if (input is List<int>)
        {
            //Use this statement if a list of integer values was passed in
            return fooList.Where(f => input.Contains(f.FooInt));
        }
        else if (input is List<string>)
        {
            //Use this statement if a list of string values was passed in
            return fooList.Where(f => input.Contains(f.FooString));
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
}
```

The same compiler errors are reported on `input.Contains(f.Property)`.

Comment: The only way this works is if `input is List<int>`, why are you using `<T>`?

Comment: Sidenote: `return bar.Intersect(input);` would be more efficient.

Comment: Because T is not int in general, and inside function at compile time you cannot assume T is int.

Comment: As Austin pointed, it works only with int. Consider if it was possible to compile and someone called `MyTest<string>(someStrings)`

Comment: can you please post a more extended version of your problem, because in this way the question makes no sense

Comment: return input.OfType<int>().Intersect(bar);  If this doesn't solve it, then please tell us what the desired output of MyTest<NotAnInt>() should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> foo = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var myResult = MyTest<int>(foo);
}

private static List<int> MyTest<T>(List<T> input)
{
    List<int> bar = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };
    return bar.Where(b => input.OfType<int>().Contains(b)).ToList();
}
```

The problem is that at the compiler has no idea what type T is. Since T could be anything you can't call a method which expects an int (`input.Contains`).

Comment: Surely changing `MyTest<T>(List<T> input)` to `MyTest<int>(List<int> input)` is preferable!

Comment: If you know input is always going to be List<int>, then sure. If you don't (and I assume that's the reason for making it generic in the first place) then it would be better to cater for different types of input.

Answer (score 2):

`input` should be a `List<int>`

and then, whenever you call the function, if `T` is not an int, you'll know that it will always return an empty list anyway.

the function doesn't make very much sense when `T` is not an int.

Answer (score 2):

also another solution

```
static void MainT(string[] args)
{
    List<int> foo = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var myResult = MyTest<int>(foo);
}

private static List<int> MyTest<T>(List<T> input) where T : IEquatable<int>
{
    List<int> bar = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };
    return bar.Where(b => input.Any(i => i.Equals(b))).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Never thought of using IEquatable<int> in the signature. The inner LINQ query (i => ...) is also very smooth and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at this function in isolation.

```
private static List<int> MyTest<T>(List<T> input)
{
    List<int> bar = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };
    return bar.Where(b => input.Contains(b)).ToList();
}
```

What if T were object... or string.. there's nothing stopping T from being those types.  If T were one of those types, the statement `input.Contains(b)` would not make sense.

The compiler is complaining because you are allowing types that do not make sense with the statements in the method body.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't guarantee that any <T> -- **any <T>** , DateTime, object, whatever -- will be castable to an int. That's why you're getting your first error.

In some circumstance you might be able to specify a kind of object in the signature of your function:

```
 private static List<int> MyTest<T>(List<T> input)  where T : someObject
```

This won't work for your case because int is a struct. You can work with it in a lot of other ways (other answers given outline some great methods), but you'll have to adjust your current strategy in some way.

Comment: T can't be object the way you put it. Object class is sealed